# How can I efficiently represent inheritance down a tree?

Tags: sql-server-2005, hierarchy

I have a database with three "levels" of objects: `A`, `B`, and `C`. Table `A` has around 100000 rows, `B` has 500000, and `C` has 2 million.

In a fit of stupidity, I designed the database to use joining tables `AB` and `BC`, even though these are 1:m and could have been represented as an `ParentA` attribute in `B` and a `ParentB` attribute in `C`. I did this because I thought at the time that these might be m:m.

Now, I also have a table `D` that has a m:m relationship with `C`. To simplify data management for users, it makes sense to allow them to relate `D` to `A` or `B` rather than directly to each `C`.

So, I have joining tables `DA`, `DB`, and `DC`, and a joining view `DC2` that includes `DC` as well as the inherited `DC` relationships from joins of `DA-AB-BC` and `DB-BC`. I use a UNION ALL for this, and there's some business logic to prevent users from assigning the same `D` record at two levels.

The problem is, the performance of `DC2` kinda sucks. All of the other tables have appropriate covering indexes for these joins, and the covering indexes are clustered. DC2 does not include tables `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D`, just the joining tables.

There are also tables E, F, G, and H that are similar to D in how they relate to A, B, and C.

What are some strategies I can use to improve performance of these inherited relationships?

Thought of already:

- Making `DC2` an indexed view is not an option since UNION is not permitted in an indexed view in MSSQL.
- I could make DC2 a table and manage it with triggers, but this would be a pain, and I still have EC2, FC2, etc. to deal with. I can't make it where
- Changing AB and BC into attributes of B and C might actually slow things down, since the joining tables are lighter and the main tables aren't joined to DC2 often.

Comment: What's your typical query, `select * from dc2 where d_id=X`? If that sort of query is slow the predicate must not be being pushed into the `union`. I believe there are differences between how SS2008 and SS2005 handle this but I'm no expert. Posting view DDL, an actual query and plan may help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look at your indexed view the other way around:

Have table O for your objects, storing A, B and C, and a level field. Then create indexed views for A, B and C based on queries off O. Perhaps use a hierarchyid field to know the full tree for each record.

There's plenty more you could do, but this could be a useful start.